# Do prime solutions to $XY + Z - W$ always occur in threes, modulo the obvious $XY=YX$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $ab + c = d$ has a prime solution and $ca + b = e$ is another prime solution.  Then is $bc + a = f$ another prime solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: for example, $3\cdot 4 + 7 = 19$ and $4\cdot 7 + 3 = 31$ are both prime, but $3\cdot 7 + 4 = 25$ is not.

Or if you want $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be primes as well, then $2\cdot 11 + 7 = 29$ and $7\cdot 11 + 2 = 79$ are both prime, but $2\cdot 7 + 11 = 25$ is not.